# What is the default javascript formatter plugin for vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't remember ever installing a javascript formatter with VS code I've just been using the default.

From what I can tell this plugin is the actual formatter being used

`lonefy.vscode-js-css-html-formatter`

Is this indeed the default formatter that is configured when you first install VSCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/.vscode/settings.json#L83), the default formatter is defined in a built-in extension called [typescript-language-features](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features).

Comment: There is also A **Javascript-Language-Features** so if your looking for which formatter to select from your **`.vscode/settings.json`** file, that is the one. The suggestion widget picks up on it so if you have to type it your doing something wrong. I want to note though that Mr @LexLi is very much correct though. So first off, it isn't considered a plugin, technically it's an extension, and furthermore; there is no JavaScript-Language-Features extension. I am not exactly sure who they implement it, but I know that at the core of JavaScript-Language-Features...

Comment: is TypeScript-Language-Features. The same is true for `tsconfig.json` & `jsconfig.json`, which both have the ability to set some, if not all, of the settings implemented by TypeScript-Language-Features. If you see TypeScript error codes in your JavaScript now you know why.l